# Do MySQL MEMORY tables support multi-column indexes?

Tags: mysql

i duplicated one of my myisam tables into memory and it seems like the index isn't working as it should. the index is on 3 columns, but only the 3rd column shows cardinality and the queries are extremely slow (doing full table scan for some reason).

so, do memory table not support multiple column indexes?

Comment: Have yo checked query execution plan?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they do. Max 16 columns per index, max 64 indexes per table and the total key size of a records cannot exceed about 3KB.

Look, it's [in the docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/memory-storage-engine.html).

That doesn't mean the indexes are used properly. It depends on the query and the combination, and order, of the columns in the index.